# Conversion without lossing precision from float to double and back into float

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion, double, precision

I would like to known is there a way to conver float like this 0,00749052940542251 to double without lossing precision and convert back into same float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"0,00749052940542251" is not a float - exactly.

A 32-bit float can encode about 2<sup>32</sup> different values *exactly*. 0,00749052940542251 is not one of them.    Instead when code assigns 0,00749052940542251 to a float, the float stores a nearby value:

```
0,007490529 213...  The closest float
0,007490529 40542251
0,007490529 678...  The next closest float
```

As double's precision and range exceeds float, any float --> double --> float can round-trip exactly.

---

0,00749052940542251 is not one of the about 2<sup>64</sup> different values encodable as a double either.  Again, a nearby value is used.  Closer, yet not the same.

```
0,007490529 4054225 099..
0,007490529 4054225 1
0,007490529 4054225 107..
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting from float to double does not involve a loss of precision, as double is a higher-precision type than float.

However, your example number is too precise for the float type - storing that number in a float will always involve a loss of precision, because your number has 15 significant digits, and a float can only store 6 to 9 significant digits. A double can store 15 to 16. To understand better why this is, I've included some articles below from wikipedia. You may want to read more on floating-point numbers, which C#'s float and double types both are.

Further reading:
 [Wikipedia - Single (C# float)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) 

[Wikipedia - Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

[Wikipedia - Floating-point Arithemtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

Comment: "a float can only store 6 to 9 significant digits." Counter example, a float can store 2^-24 exactly.  And that has 17 significant digits: 0.000000059604644775390625.  A float can store all 6 significant digits numbers in range. 10+/-38.  It can also store exactly many select values exceeding 6 digits.

Comment: @Chux - that's not really how floating-point numbers work. I was summarizing for the general case. It's certainly true that the exact decimal representations may have more than six significant digits, and also that denormal representations behave differently. Neither of these were particularly relevant to the question. For numbers that aren't the specific numbers which are representable in the denormal range, 6 to 9 decimal digits of precision is a good, understandable approximation. Because it's a binary floating-point format, it doesn't map well to decimal concepts.